# Discord.Py Assigning values to variables

Tags: python, datetime, variables, timer, discord.py

```py
@commands.command()
    async def reroll(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, id_ : int):

      try:
        new_gaw_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(id_)
      except:
        await ctx.send("Failed to parse command. ID was incorrect.")
        return
        
      winners = int(winners.replace("W",""))
      users_mention = []
      for i in range(winners):
        users = await new_gaw_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(self.client.user))
        winner = random.choice(users)
        users_mention.append(winner.mention)
        users.remove(winner)
        
        displayed_winners = ",".join(users_mention)

      await ctx.send(f"Congragulations {displayed_winners}! You have won the **{prize}**.\n{gaw_msg.jump_url}")
```

variable winners is referenced before assignment. I gave value to winners before using it so idk why it doesnt work. Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: Can you provide the full Traceback?

Comment: `UnboundLocalError : Variable "winners" referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to perform an operation on the `winners` variable before it was created.

There is a thing called name "namespace". Basically, variables created globally (without indent) and variables created locally (inside functions or loops) are different variables.

If you want to specifically use a global variable inside the function, you should first declare that the variable will be global by writing `global variable_name` inside the function. And only then you can perform operations with it.

There are some hidden dangers with the usage of global variables, so I suggest [you read more about python namespaces](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namespaces-and-scope-in-python/) and [global keyword](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword) by yourself.

Comment: from what i saw , it means i have to define the variable , no ? However putting is as an arg like : winners = int : 1 , would do the work ?

Comment: @TheFabolousDust, sorry, I don't fully understand what do you mean. To use the global variable inside the function, you have to first declare that it is global. To do this, you have to write `global winners` and then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: yea no problem , the docs helped ty.